# Change mysql column encoding from latin1_swedish_ci to binary

Tags: mysql, encoding, dataset

I currently have a table with a column of varchar(16) latin1_swedish_ci currently with only letters and numbers ([a-zA-Z0-9]) and I'd like to change its type to char(16) and its encoding to binary.

Am I going to lose data? Or this character set can map to binary?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run some querys to test this.

**to create an test table LIKE the old table**

```
CREATE TABLE database.test LIKE database.your_table;
```

**to alter your_latin1_varchar_column to binary chars**

```
ALTER TABLE database.your_table MODIFY your_latin1_varchar_column char(16) CHARACTER SET binary;
```

**Copy your data into your new table and make sure where where no warnings about charset encoding of data loses by truncates**

```
INSERT INTO database.your_table SELECT * FROM database.test;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

**Note the INSERT INTO... query above could be slow on an large table with many records**